# If condition with and operator

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

How to use IF condition with AND operator?
I'm getting an error

```
(princ"Enter a year: ")
(defvar y(read))
(defun leap-year(y)
    (if(and(= 0(mod y 400)(= 0(mod y 4))
       (print"Is a leap year"))
       (print"Is not"))))

(leap-year y)
```

Comment: Error messages are important, please tell which error is being reported when describing a bug/problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your code should ideally look like this:

```
(princ "Enter a year: ")
(finish-output)             ; make sure that output is done

(defvar *year*              ; use the usual naming convention for
                            ;  global variables.
  (let ((*read-eval* nil))  ; don't run code during reading
    (read)))

(defun leap-year-p (y)
  ; your implementation here
  ; return a truth value
  )

(print (if (leap-year-p *year*) "yes" "no"))
```

Alternatively it also is a good idea to not work on the top-level with function calls and global variables. Write procedures/functions for everything. That way your code automatically is more modular, testable and reusable.

```
(defun prompt-for-year ()
  (princ "Enter a year: ")
  (finish-output)
  (let ((*read-eval* nil))
    (read)))

(defun leap-year-p (y)
  ; your implementation here
  ; return a truth value
  )

(defun check-leap-year ()
  (print (if (leap-year-p (prompt-for-year))
             "yes"
           "no")))

(check-leap-year)
```

Answer (score 3):

How often happens in lisp languages, the problem is in missing (or extra) parentheses.

In your case you have multiple parentheses issues in the definition of the function, which should be:

```
(defun leap-year (y)
  (if (and (= 0 (mod y 400)) (= 0(mod y 4)))
      (print "Is a leap year")
      (print "Is not")))
```

A good discipline on expression alignments and a good program editor like for instance Emacs are in fact very important (I would say “essential”) in programming in these languages.

Note that if you use the function in a REPL, you could omit the `print`:

```
(defun leap-year (y)
  (if (and (= 0 (mod y 400)) (= 0(mod y 4)))
      "Is a leap year"
      "Is not"))
```

Finally, note that the check for a leap year is [incorrect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm). A correct definition could be the following:

```
(defun leap-year (y)
  (cond ((/= 0 (mod y 4)) "no")
        ((/= 0 (mod y 100)) "yes")
        ((/= 0 (mod y 400)) "no")
        (t "yes")))
```

or, with the `if`:

```
(defun leap-year (y)
  (if (or (and (zerop (mod y 4))
               (not (zerop (mod y 100))))
          (zerop (mod y 400)))
      "yes"
      "no"))
```

Comment: I'm using command prompt and notepad. I tried to run your codes, and the output did not showed up. I don't know why.

Comment: In command prompt you should keep the `print`.